# Applying for Indian e-Visa

Tags: india, tourist-visas

Can you please tell me what the official website is to apply for an Indian e-visa as I am wary of scam sites.

Answer (score 2):

You don’t say where you’re applying from (and I don’t know if it matters), however this is the site linked from the gov.uk travel advice page for British citizens: https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html

Comment: Yes. That is the correct website. Additionally, gov.in domain is given only to government websites.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't matter from where you apply (as long you are from a country were eVisa is allowed). Just: it is a ugly site, and not obvious to use: Take time and check twice every action (and question) you write. Keep a note file and save application numbers and links you may get. You will get strange errors (photo of passport should be pdf (in mac: "reduced size"), but your photo should be jpeg).

Comment: I also found that it was better to use Chrome than Internet Explorer as my photo did not load correctly when I used IE.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for help with your visa application [indianvisa.online](https://indianvisa.online) can help. Please call us to know your options.